# Angular2 SEO tags and prerendering

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have created Angular2 (Angular 4.4.3) app with dynamic content loaded over API.

I have used official docs for setting title and meta (Added in v4): 
https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title
https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

And I have used this guide to create prerender server: 
https://blog.pusher.com/make-angular-4-app-seo-friendly/
(skip to: Creating an Express server to make your Angular app SEO friendly)

But it's not working as described. For example, in AppComponent.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(public router: Router,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private titleService: Title) {
    this.titleService.setTitle("SOME CUSTOM TITLE");
  }
```

And when I open page, I see that set as Title in browser, but when opening source of page, I see this:

[image]
I have also used regular build, and AOT build but same thing, here's conf:
tsconfig-aot.json:

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "typeRoots": [
          "./node_modules/@types/"
        ]
      },

      "files": [
        "src/app/app.module.ts",
        "src/main.ts"
      ],

      "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": "aot",
        "skipMetadataEmit" : true
      }
    }
tsconfig.app.json
    {
      "extends": "../tsconfig-aot.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "module": "es2015",
        "types": []
      },
      "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
      ]
    }
```

How can I set meta title / description from AppComponent or if possible from some other child component so it can be visible in source code, or when google crawls site?

Answer (score 0):

Actually a problem was serving content from server. I have tried to serve content directly with Nginx, but thing is that node should run server pack first, and then connect with Nginx as proxy only.